# How to get the cell unformatted value in POI XSSF event model?

Tags: excel, apache-poi, xssf

cell A1 has the ***formula "=A2"*** and is formatted to show 1 decimal point

cell A2 has the ***value 4.23***

cell A1 shows 4.2  (formatted display value)

cell A2 shows 4.23 (formatted display value)

My XSSF eventmodel sheetContentHandler class implements

> public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue,
>   XSSFComment comment)

but formattedValue returns 4.2 for cell A1, and i want to retrieve the **unformattedValue** 4.23

How can i do this ?
(I can't change to usermodel, i have huge files)

Comment: Short answer - write your own SAX handler for processing the sheet XML. It's not too hard to do, but it's certainly more work than just using `XSSFSheetXMLHandler` (which handles formatting internally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok There is no way to do this using the sheetContentHandler (though you could get the actual formula if you want there, but that is not what i am looking for)

The only solution will be to use a SheetHandler class which extends DefaultHandler.

Example code on apache-poi site:
[Example](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api)

Answer (score 1):

If the only problem is numerical value formatting, you can pass in a custom DataFormatter to the XSSFSheetXMLHandler and continue to user the SheetContentsHandler interface.

Just override the main formatRawCellContents(...) method to not format the value and return the raw value.
e.g.

```
@Override
public String formatRawCellContents(double value, int formatIndex, String formatString, boolean use1904Windowing) {
    return Double.toString(value);
}
```

This makes it much easier for dates as well as you don't have to muck around reversing date formats, just use DateUtil.getJavaDate() for the value.

Comment: I've also liked the formatting option by using the toPlainString() method of BigDecimal, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431561/apache-poi-dataformatter-returns-scientific-notation