# Apache POI How to add a custom DataFormatter for handling 13 digit integers as strings, not numbers

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm building a XLSX processor that transforms a XLSX into a CSV file. Because the files can get quite big, I'm using the event-based approach using XSSFSheetXMLHandler

This works perfectly fine, but my XLSX files contains long numbers (13 digits) which are unique identification numbers, not real numbers. When running my code on a Windows machine it correctly extracts the numbers, but when running on a Linux machine it converts it to E-notation.

For example: the source value is 7401075293087. On windows this is correctly extracted into my CSV, but on Linux the value comes through as 7.40108E+12

The problem with the XSSFSheetXMLHandler is that it reads the XLSX under the covers and then throws events that are caught by a SheetContentsHandler that you need to implement. Once of the method in the SheetContentsHandler is a cell method with the signature: cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue, XSSFComment comment)

As your can see, this method already received the formatted cell (so in my case it receives "7.40108E+12"). All the rest of the logic happens under the covers.

Based on my investigations I believe the solution lies in defining a custom DataFormatter that will specifically treat 13 digit integers as a string, instead of formatting them as E-notation.

Unfortunately my plan didn't work as expected and I couldn't find an help online. Below is an extract of my code. I tried the following in the processSheet method:

```
     Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").setRegion("ZA").build(); 
     DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(locale);
     Format format = new MessageFormat("{0,number,full}");
     formatter.addFormat("#############", format);
```

Here's an extract of my code:

The main body of the code:

```
 public void process(String Filename)throws IOException, OpenXML4JException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
     ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings = new ReadOnlySharedStringsTable(this.xlsxPackage);
     XSSFReader xssfReader = new XSSFReader(this.xlsxPackage);
     StylesTable styles = xssfReader.getStylesTable();
     XSSFReader.SheetIterator iter = (XSSFReader.SheetIterator) xssfReader.getSheetsData();
     while (iter.hasNext()) {
          InputStream stream = iter.next();
          String sheetName = iter.getSheetName();
          outStream = new FileOutputStream(Filename);
          logger.info(sheetName);
          this.output = new  PrintWriter(Filename);
          processSheet(styles, strings, new SheetToCSV(), stream);
          logger.info("Done with Sheet   :"+sheetName);
          output.flush();
          stream.close();
          outStream.close();
          output.close();
         ++index; 
     }
 } 

 public void processSheet(StylesTable styles,ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings,SheetContentsHandler sheetHandler, InputStream sheetInputStream)
         throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

     InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheetInputStream);
     try {
         XMLReader sheetParser = SAXHelper.newXMLReader();
         ContentHandler handler = new XSSFSheetXMLHandler(styles, null, strings, sheetHandler, formatter, false);
         sheetParser.setContentHandler(handler);
         sheetParser.parse(sheetSource);
      } catch(ParserConfigurationException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException("SAX parser appears to be broken - " + e.getMessage());
      }
 }
```

And here's the custom handler:

```
private class SheetToCSV implements SheetContentsHandler {
         private boolean firstCellOfRow = false;
         private int currentRow = -1;
         private int currentCol = -1;

     private void outputMissingRows(int number) {

         for (int i=0; i<number; i++) {
             for (int j=0; j<minColumns; j++) {
                 output.append(',');
             }
             output.append('\n');
         }
     }

     public void startRow(int rowNum) {
         // If there were gaps, output the missing rows
         outputMissingRows(rowNum-currentRow-1);
         // Prepare for this row
         firstCellOfRow = true;
         currentRow = rowNum;
         currentCol = -1;
     }

     public void endRow(int rowNum) {
         // Ensure the minimum number of columns
         for (int i=currentCol; i<minColumns; i++) {
             output.append(',');
         }
         output.append('\n');
     }

     public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue,
             XSSFComment comment) {
         logger.info("CellRef :: Formatted Value   :"+cellReference+" :: "+formattedValue);              
         if (firstCellOfRow) {
             firstCellOfRow = false;
         } else {
             output.append(',');
         }

         // gracefully handle missing CellRef here in a similar way as XSSFCell does
         if(cellReference == null) {
             cellReference = new CellRangeAddress(currentRow, currentCol, currentCol, currentCol).formatAsString();
         }

         // Did we miss any cells?
         int thisCol = (new CellReference(cellReference)).getCol();
         int missedCols = thisCol - currentCol - 1;
         for (int i=0; i<missedCols; i++) {
             output.append(',');
         }
         currentCol = thisCol;

         // Number or string?
         try {
             Double.parseDouble(formattedValue);
             output.append(formattedValue);
         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
             //formattedValue = formattedValue.replaceAll("\\t", "");
             //formattedValue = formattedValue.replaceAll("\\n", "");
             //formattedValue = formattedValue.trim();
             output.append('"');
             output.append(formattedValue.replace("\"", "\\\"").trim());
             output.append('"');
         }
     }

     public void headerFooter(String text, boolean isHeader, String tagName) {
         // Skip, no headers or footers in CSV
     }

    @Override
    public void ovveriddenFormat(String celRef, int formatIndex,
            String formatedString) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cannot reproducing if the file is generated using `Excel` and the cells containing the 13 digit numbers are formatted using number format `0` or `#`, **not** `General`.

But what is meant with "running on a Linux machine"? If I am creating the `*.xlsx` file using `Libreoffice Calc` having the cells containing the 13 digit numbers formatted using number format `General`, then `Calc` will showing them as 13 digit numbers but `Excel` will not. For showing the numbers 13 digit in `Excel` the cells must be formatted using number format `0` or `#`.

The `apache poi` `DataFormatter` is made to work like `Excel` would do. And `Excel` shows values from 12 digits on as scientific notation when formatted using `General`.

You could changing this behavior using:

```
...
    public void processSheet(
            StylesTable styles,
            ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings,
            SheetContentsHandler sheetHandler, 
            InputStream sheetInputStream) throws IOException, SAXException {
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        formatter.addFormat("General", new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.###############"));
...
```

Comment: Tx Axel. Your suggestion sorted me out. Regarding your other comments: Unfortunately I have zero control over the formatting of the source file, so I have to process what I've got (and I get many different formats, so trying to be generic).

Comment: W.r.t comment re Linux machine: My main dev box is an Ubuntu 16.04 machine, which gave the errror as described. When I ran the code on the customer's Windows laptop the error did not happen. Exact same file, exact same code-base. As a result I assumed it was some locale-specific issue

Comment: Just for the record, I added the formatted as follows: formatter.addFormat("General", new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.##########################"));
This was necessary since other fields in my XLSX contained values like 0.00160455519952056

Answer (score 1):

DZONE wrote a cracking article on this:
https://dzone.com/articles/simple-string-representation-of-java-decimal-numbe

Another answer from StackOverflow is:

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
Object o = getCellValue(row.getCell(0));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(o.toString()).toPlainString());
```

REF: [Apache POI DataFormatter Returns Scientific Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431561/apache-poi-dataformatter-returns-scientific-notation)

I didn't test your actual problem on a linux machine.. however I hope this provides some answers in the midst of the night!