# How to read an integer cell value as string without any alteration from an excel (xlsx) file using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel file that contains this cell value 7501035907584
I want to be able to read the cell value into a string variable without any alteration. What I tried to use was the DataFormatter class but the result of the formatting was "7.50104E+12" which is not what I want. Is there a way to tell Apache POI to read the numeric cell value as it is?

This is the code I used:

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter()
String barcode = formatter.formatCellValue(cell)
```

Note: I don't want to change the cell type because it's haram according to the holy docs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368640/apache-poi-how-to-add-a-custom-dataformatter-for-handling-13-digit-integers-as-s/49369659#49369659.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682898/how-do-i-edit-pattern-in-dataformatter/51683823#51683823.

Comment: @AxelRichter I've found a less complex solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to convert:
numericCellValue -> BigDecimal -> BigInteger -> String

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(cell.numericCellValue).toBigInteger().toString()
```