# csvWriter write long number in cell in Java

Tags: java

While writing the excel file is fine I see that really long numbers are scientific notations in excel

Example: 8.71129E+12

instead of: 1234567890

How can I do it in Java

I am writing like

```
String nart = "1236547865452";
csvWriter.append(nart);
```

Comment: That is not a formula; it is scientific notation.

Comment: Is there anyway I can stop excel from converting it. And show the numbers as string without manually changing the format of the column.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/452832/turn-off-scientific-notation-in-excel and may be try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431561/apache-poi-dataformatter-returns-scientific-notation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the same can be achieved using writing to simple CSV? ,

but through **APACHE POI** You can write to excel and you need to do set the cell type if you want to see the whole value like  *1236547865452* `cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);` and this is not needed it you have to see scientific notation as *8.71129E+12*